# Need help in combining output of a python function

Tags: python

I have output to a python function:

```
"top_duration": [
{
"duration": 3752,
"image_name": "ohcm-designer-orchestration-service"
},
{
"duration": 3471,
"image_name": "ohcm-designer-orchestration-service"
},
{
"duration": 3452,
"image_name": "metadata-validations-service"
},
{
"duration": 120,
"image_name": "metadata-validations-service"
},
{
"duration": 114,
"image_name": "metadata-validations-service"
},
{
"duration": 111,
"image_name": "ohcm-metadata-dna-service"
},
{
"duration": 102,
"image_name": "metadata-validations-service"
},
{
"duration": 100,
"image_name": "metadata-runtime-proxy-service"
},
```

I want to convert the above into the format like `{Sum of Duration, image_name}`

For e.g. output: `{3452+120+114+102, "metadata-validations-service"}`
Final output: `{3788, "metadata-validations-service"}`

What approach can I take to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? I'm not sure sets really make sense for the output.

Comment: Can you post the code which outputs this?

Comment: So are you asking how to sum the durations for elements of `top_duration` that have equivalent `image_name`s?

Comment: Did you mean that you want a dictionary mapping image names to the total duration? Or did you want a list of tuples?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I am just going through learning part yet. About the output I shared was in json format fetched from kibana logs. I just want to get the sum of duration of each service (by service name I mean image_name) combined in one.

Comment: @TomB. Yes I want the sum of duration of image_names

Comment: @decorator-factory I want output to be in tuple format like ((sum of duration, Image_name1).(sum of duration, image_name2), so on...)

Comment: @decorator-factory yes or you suggest something else to achieve it?

Comment: So what part are you having trouble with? How would you do this by hand, for example? You would probably keep track of each image in a table, starting with 0 on each entry. Then, as you go through the list of entries, add the `duration` to the entry corresponding to the `image_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_data = {"top_duration": [
    {
        "duration": 3752,
        "image_name": "ohcm-designer-orchestration-service"
    },
    {
        "duration": 3471,
        "image_name": "ohcm-designer-orchestration-service"
    },
    {
        "duration": 3452,
        "image_name": "metadata-validations-service"
    },
    {
        "duration": 120,
        "image_name": "metadata-validations-service"
    },
    {
        "duration": 114,
        "image_name": "metadata-validations-service"
    },
    {
        "duration": 111,
        "image_name": "ohcm-metadata-dna-service"
    },
    {
        "duration": 102,
        "image_name": "metadata-validations-service"
    },
    {
        "duration": 100,
        "image_name": "metadata-runtime-proxy-service"
    }]}


final_dict_data = defaultdict(int)
for item in dict_data['top_duration']:
    final_dict_data[item['image_name']] += item['duration']
    
final_dict_data = {val:key for key,val in final_dict_data.items()}
```

```
{7223: 'ohcm-designer-orchestration-service',
 3788: 'metadata-validations-service',
 111: 'ohcm-metadata-dna-service',
 100: 'metadata-runtime-proxy-service'}
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it, is using pandas:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
data = json.dumps({
"top_duration": [
{
"duration": 3752,
"image_name": "ohcm-designer-orchestration-service"
},
{
"duration": 3471,
"image_name": "ohcm-designer-orchestration-service"
},
{
"duration": 3452,
"image_name": "metadata-validations-service"
},
{
"duration": 120,
"image_name": "metadata-validations-service"
},
{
"duration": 114,
"image_name": "metadata-validations-service"
},
{
"duration": 111,
"image_name": "ohcm-metadata-dna-service"
},
{
"duration": 102,
"image_name": "metadata-validations-service"
},
{
"duration": 100,
"image_name": "metadata-runtime-proxy-service"
}]
})

file = json.loads(data)
df2 = json_normalize(file['top_duration'])

new_df = df2.groupby(['image_name'])['duration'].sum().reset_index()
```

output:

```
                            image_name  duration
0       metadata-runtime-proxy-service       100
1         metadata-validations-service      3788
2  ohcm-designer-orchestration-service      7223
3            ohcm-metadata-dna-service       111
```